# Google Sheets - Arrayformula with Xlookup

Tags: array-formulas, xlookup

When using xlookup in arrayformula, the result range is limited to one column.

arrayformula(xlookup(A10:A55,A3:A8,B3:C8,,0)) returns 1 column on matches

xlookup(A10:A55,A3:A8,B3:C8,,0) returns 2 columns on matches

Is there some limitation with arrayformula returning arrays?

I tried named ranges, and {list of columns}